# Post data in python with requests module and add header

Tags: python, session, http-post, python-requests

I want to post my data to url but it does not work. what I tried in python is: (script.py)

```
session=requests.Session()
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
session.headers.update(headers)
post_data={'login':'login', 'username':'user', 'password':'password'}
post_response=session.post(url='https://website.com', data=post_data)
print post_response.content
sys.exit()
```

When I want to run script in this way:

```
python script.py | w3m -T text/html
```

It returns me the error:

`Your browser is the problem. please use firefox or chrome or ...`

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Well, clearly the browser you're using (`w3m`) isn't firefox or chrome. Try `python script.py > output_file` and see what you got back from the server. If that works tell us what `output_file` contains.

Comment: No it doesn't work also without w3m @Reut Sharabani

Comment: what is the content of the output file you redirected to?

Comment: There are probably hidden form fields that need to be scraped in order to log-in. I doubt user-agent spoofing alone will get you very far.

Comment: I would sniff the traffic logging from a real browser first, then try to emulate the request using python with all the needed information. You can use a plugin like Tamper Header for Firefox to see these requests.